# How to stop this double range slider at a certain point?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm working on a double range slider, I have combined two range sliders into a single range slider using CSS. The code works as expected but I want to stop the sliders from moving if gap between both sliders is equal to 5 (Similar to [this](https://metroui.org.ua/double-slider.html)).

Currently my code stops the left slider from moving ahead if the gap is equal to 5 but I can move the right slider towards left which is not expected.

Here's the code:

```js
window.onload=()=>slide();
        /*Display values based on range*/
function slide(){
    let displayValue_left=document.getElementById('range1');
    let displayValue_right=document.getElementById('range2');
    let slideValue_left = document.getElementById("slider1");            
    let slideValue_right = document.getElementById("slider2");
    //Check if difference of left and right slider is less than or equal to 5
    if(parseInt(slideValue_right.value)-parseInt(slideValue_left.value)<=5){
        //if yes then set left slider value to value of right slider-5
                         slideValue_left.value=slideValue_right.value-5;

        //if left slider value=0 right slider value = 5(to maintain gap)
        if(parseInt(slideValue_left.value)==0){
            document.getElementById("slider2").value=parseInt(slideValue_left.value)+5;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('range1').innerText=slideValue_left.value;
    document.getElementById('range2').innerText=slideValue_right.value; 
}
```

```css
*,
  *:before,
  *:after{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}
.container{
    width: 95vmin;
    height: 67.5vmin;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
#slider1,#slider2{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute; 
    background-color: transparent;
    /*Ignore Mouse pointer/Don't respond to mouse pointer event*/
    pointer-events: none;
}
/*
    Styling the track(range line)
*/
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: red;
    height: 2px;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track{
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background-color: red;   
    height: 2px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track{
    appearance: none;
    background-color: red;   
    height: 2px;
}
/*
    Styling for Thumb
*/
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    /*Respond to pointer event*/
    pointer-events: auto;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb{
    appearance: none;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Double Range Slider</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" oninput="slide()" id="slider1">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="10" oninput="slide()" id="slider2">
        <div id="values">
            <div>
                Range1:
                <span id="range1"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                Range2:
                <span id="range2"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself by making separate functions for left, right slider and checking for same condition in both the functions. Thought of answering here so that people may refer it later.

```js
window.onload=()=>{
    slideleft()
    slideright()
}
let displayValue_left=document.getElementById('range1');
let slideValue_left = document.getElementById("slider1");
let displayValue_right=document.getElementById('range2');
let slideValue_right = document.getElementById("slider2");
// For left slider
function slideleft(){
    //Check if difference of left and right slider is less than or equal to 5
    if(parseInt(slideValue_right.value)-parseInt(slideValue_left.value)<=5){
        //if yes then set left slider value to value of right slider-5
        slideValue_left.value=parseInt(slideValue_right.value)-5;
    }
    displayValue_left.innerText=slideValue_left.value;
}
//For right slider
function slideright(){
    //Check if difference of left and right slider is less than or equal to 5
    if(parseInt(slideValue_right.value)-parseInt(slideValue_left.value)<=5){
        //if yes then set right slider value to value of left slider+5
        slideValue_right.value=parseInt(slideValue_left.value)+5;
    }
    displayValue_right.innerText=slideValue_right.value;
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}
.container{
    width: 95vmin;
    height: 67.5vmin;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
#slider1,#slider2{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute; 
    background-color: transparent;
    /*Ignore Mouse pointer/Don't respond to mouse pointer event*/
    pointer-events: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: red;
    height: 2px;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track{
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background-color: red;   
    height: 2px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track{
    appearance: none;
    background-color: red;   
    height: 2px;
}
/*
    Styling for Thumb
*/
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    /*Respond to pointer event*/
    pointer-events: auto;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb{
    appearance: none;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Double Range Slider</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" oninput="slideleft()" id="slider1">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="10" oninput="slideright()" id="slider2">        
        <div id="values">
            <div>
                Range1:
                <span id="range1"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                Range2:
                <span id="range2"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```